# Django: model field having blank=True, null=True, unique=True gives troubles in the admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model in which I have:

```
ipv4_address = models.IPAddressField(verbose_name=_('ipv4 address'), blank=True, null=True, unique=True, default=None)
ipv6_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv6', verbose_name=_('ipv6 address'), blank=True, null=True, unique=True, default=None)
```

And gives me the troubles described here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4136

How can I solve this?

I was thinking of making a custom GenericIPAddressField which inserts NULL into the database instead of an empty string. What do you think? Are there other possible solutions?

Comment: did you try to override your model's save method and replace the empty string with None there?

Comment: tried this but didn't work. I get the validation error anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suggestion of a custom field `GenericIPAddressField` is probably the most DRY solution. akonsu's suggestion in the comments above to override the save method is a good one. A quick hack I have used is to clean the value to `None` in your model form.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean_ipv6_address(self):
        """
        Return None instead of empty string
        """
        return self.cleaned_data.get('ipv6_address') or None
```

If you edit the model through the django admin, use your model form there

```
#!admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: tried and it works thanks! Had to do something similar for the inline_formset stuff.