# Django unique=True except for blank values

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True, validators=[validate_serial], unique=True)
    ....
```

serial_number can be blank and null because all parts don't necessarily have a serial number.  However, after storing one part without a serial number, blank is no longer unique and I get this error:

*Part with this Serial number already exists.*

Is there a workaround for this?  I already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742845/937147), but I don't have a modelform.  I either use the admin or do it directly in the code.

Comment: If you use the admin, then you can define a custom model form. I showed how in the answer you linked to. If you're doing it in code, just set `part.serial_number=None` instead of using "" for blank values.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue and fixed it by specifying `None` for the field when saving.

Specifying `default=None` could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

Django supports creating unique constraints that have conditions. A custom constraint can be created that enforces uniqueness for a given field only under the condition that a field's value is not blank.

```py
from django.db.models import Q

serialnumber_is_not_blank = ~Q(serial_number="")

class Meta:
   constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=["serial_number"],
            condition=serialnumber_is_not_blank,
            name="unique_serial_number",
        )
    ]
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that having null values aren't taken into account in uniqueness constraints. The way to get around this is to not use null, but instead use an empty string. So, remove `null=True`.

Comment: Yes, you can have more than null in a unique column. However, the OP wants to allow more than one empty value. Therefore they have to allow null, because the uniqueness checks only allow one empty string.